# Stored Proc receives comma sep list of ID want to retrieve comma sep list of decoded values

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @x varchar(250), @xx xml
```

If my incoming list of dept ids in my SP looks like this:

```
set @x = '3, 9, 10, 12, 14'
```

I can easily convert it into XML and query it like this:

```
set @xx = '<xml><e>' + REPLACE(@x,', ','</e><e>') + '</e></xml>'

select @xx
```

Returns:

```
<xml><e>3</e><e>9</e><e>10</e><e>12</e><e>14</e></xml>
```

And

```
select @xx.query('for $d in /xml/e return data($d)')
```

Returns:

```
3 9 10 12 14
```

Using XML path I can manually get the comma separated list of Dept Names when I know the DeptIDs before hand

```
select SUBSTRING((SELECT (', '+DeptName) from vDepartments where DeptID in (3, 9, 10, 12, 14) for xml path('')), 3, 1000)
```

But, I think I should be able to do this from the XML above:

```
select SUBSTRING((SELECT (', '+DeptName) from vDepartments where DeptID in @xx.query('for $d in /xml/e return string($d)') for xml path('')), 3, 1000)
```

Comment: What's the error?  You have communicated what you'd like to do... but not what happens when you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the id's from the parameter in a table variable and use that in a join against vDepartment

```
-- Comma separated parameter
declare @x varchar(250)
set @x = '3, 9, 10, 12, 14'

-- Convert to xml
declare @xx xml
set @xx = '<xml><e>' + REPLACE(@x,', ','</e><e>') + '</e></xml>'

-- Table variable to hold ID's from parameter
declare @T table(ID int)

-- Get ID's from xml
insert into @T (ID)
select N.value('.', 'int')
from @xx.nodes('xml/e') as T(N)

-- Use the table in a inner join.
select stuff(
(select ', '+DeptName
 from vDepartments as D
   inner join @T as T
     on D.DeptID = T.ID
 for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2,  '')
```

If you use `.value` to extract the comma separated list of departments you will have no trouble with `<>&'"` in department names.

**Edit 1**

A version that use a recursive CTE to get the ID's instead of converting to XML. All in one query.

```
;with cte(ID, Rest) as
(
  select cast(left(@x, charindex(',', @x+',')-1) as int),
         stuff(@x, 1, charindex(',', @x+','), '')+','
  where len(@x) > 0       
  union all
  select cast(left(Rest, charindex(',', Rest)-1) as int),
         stuff(Rest, 1, charindex(',', Rest), '')
  from cte
  where len(Rest) > 1
)
select stuff(
(select ', '+DeptName
 from vDepartments as D
   inner join cte as T
     on D.DeptID = T.ID
 for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2,  '')
```